# Why is matplotlib plotting two axis labels in this example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axis-labels

I have the following code to generate 4 scatter plots:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 12))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2, hspace=0, wspace=0)
(ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4) = gs.subplots(sharex='col', sharey='row')

ax1.scatter(list(range(1,m+1)), m_list_10[2], c='red', label='Data points')
ax1.set_xlabel('Sample number', fontsize=14)
ax1.set_ylabel('Unbiased Varianve', fontsize=14)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
ax1.set_xlim(-10,110)
ax1.set_ylim(0.4,1.6)
ax1.set_title('Sample size n=10', fontsize = 16)
ax1.axhline(y=sigma, color='black', linestyle='-', label = 'Known Variance')
ax1.legend(fontsize=14)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.scatter(list(range(1,m+1)), m_list_100[2], c='orange', label='Data points')
ax2.set_xlabel('Sample number', fontsize=14)
ax2.set_ylabel('Unbiased Variance', fontsize=14)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
ax2.set_xlim(-10,110)
ax2.set_ylim(0.4,1.6)
ax2.set_title('Sample size n=100', fontsize = 16)
ax2.axhline(y=sigma, color='black', linestyle='-', label = 'Known Variance')
ax2.legend(fontsize=14)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.scatter(list(range(1,m+1)), m_list_10[3], c='blue', label='Data points')
ax3.set_xlabel('Sample number', fontsize=14)
ax3.set_ylabel('Biased Varianve', fontsize=14)
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
ax3.set_xlim(-10,110)
ax3.set_ylim(0.4,1.6)
#ax3.set_title('Sample size n=10', fontsize = 16)
ax3.axhline(y=sigma, color='black', linestyle='-', label = 'Known Variance')
ax3.legend(fontsize=14)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax4.scatter(list(range(1,m+1)), m_list_100[3], c='purple', label='Data points')
ax4.set_xlabel('Sample number', fontsize=14)
ax4.set_ylabel('Biased Variance', fontsize=14)
ax4.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
ax4.set_xlim(-10,110)
ax4.set_ylim(0.4,1.6)
#ax4.set_title('Sample size n=100', fontsize = 16)
ax4.axhline(y=sigma, color='black', linestyle='-', label = 'Known Variance')
ax4.legend(fontsize=14)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```

I want the subplots to share the y-axis columnwise and the x-axis rowwise. Unfortunatly, what I get is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the second axis labels?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to remove `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)` (and similar for `ax3` and `ax4`).  These axes (subplots) are already created via `(ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4) = gs.subplots(...)` and calling `add_subplot` you create them a second time.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you!